# Go html template access struct fields inside range

Tags: html, templates, go

Given below struct, I want to access `field2` while iterating over `field1` data in html. How do I do this?

```
var MyPageData struct {
      field1 []Foo
      field2 map[string]Bar
}
```

I tried: Inside Handler function:

```
err := myPageTemplate.Execute(w,MyPageData{ field1: field1Slice, field2 : myMapData})
```

Template:

```
     {{ range $index, $fooInstance := .field1}} 
        <tr>
            <td>{{$fooInstance.Name}}</td> //This prints the Name value
            <td>{{ index .$field2 "myKey".Name }}</td>
```

How do I access `field2` above and specify a key value to retrieve `Bar` instance?

**UPDATE** Adding Foo and Bar structs

```
type Foo2 struct {
    Name string
    Id  int 
}


type Foo struct {
    Name string
    element Foo2
}

type Bar struct {
    Name string
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No matter what the value of the pipeline is (which is denoted by the dot `.` in the template), you can use the `$` to refer to the data value you passed to [`Template.Execute()`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#Template.Execute). The `{{range}}` action iterates over the elements and it sets the pipeline (`.`) to the current item, so `.` always denotes the current item, `$` is absolutely refers to the "top level" data passed to `Template.Execute()`.

This is documented in [`text/template`](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/):

> When execution begins, $ is set to the data argument passed to Execute, that is, to the starting value of dot.

Also note that you have to export struct fields to be available in templates. So change your `MyPageData` type to:

```
type MyPageData struct {
    Field1 []Foo
    Field2 map[string]Bar
}
```

Also note that you can simply access map elements using the `.` operator. So you can access the value of the `Field2` map associated with the `"myKey"` key like this, inside the `{{range}}` action too:

```
{{$.Field2.myKey}}
```

See this simple example:

```
type MyPageData struct {
    Field1 []Foo
    Field2 map[string]Bar
}

type Foo struct {
    Name string
}

type Bar struct {
    Name string
}

func main() {
    t := template.Must(template.New("").Parse(templ))
    mpd := MyPageData{
        Field1: []Foo{{"First"}, {"Second"}},
        Field2: map[string]Bar{"myKey": {"MyValue"}},
    }
    t.Execute(os.Stdout, mpd)
}

const templ = `{{range $idx, $foo := .Field1}}{{$.Field2.myKey}} {{$idx}} - {{$foo.Name}}
{{end}}`
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/6GxoiWc1eG)):

```
{MyValue} 0 - First
{MyValue} 1 - Second
```

Also note that insdie the `{{range}}` instead of `$foo.Name` you can simply use `{{.Name}}` as the dot `.` denotes `$foo`, the current item.

If you want to lookup a value from `Field2` with a dynamic key, you do need to use the `{{index}}` action. For example if you want the value associated with the key being `$foo.Name`:

```
{{index $.Field2 $foo.Name}}
```

Or short:

```
{{index $.Field2 .Name}}
```

And going forward, if the value associated with the key is a struct for example, and you only need a field of this struct, let's say `Id`, you can use parenthesis:

```
{{(index $.Field2 .Name).Id}}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I updated the question with sample structs. `myKey` is `$foo.Name`. I tried {{$.Field2.foo.Name}} But it did not work.

Comment: @sumanj Then you do need to use the `{{index}}` action, for example: `{{index $.Field2 .Name}}`. See edited answer.

Comment: Awesome. But if`{{index $.Field2 .Name}}` is of type Foo2. and I need to print Id of Foo2 element. I tried `{{index $.Field2 .Name .Id}}`. It didn't work.

Comment: Nevermind. Got it. I had to use "(" and ")" around the pipeline snippet.